# How to send a string to the application currently on the foreground?(Like Windows On Screen Keyboard)

Tags: c#

This example code sends a string to notepad:

```
// import the function in your class
[DllImport ("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

//...

Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if( p != null)
{
   IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
   SetForegroundWindow(h);
   SendKeys.SendWait("k");
}
```

But I want to send a string to the application that is currently on the foreground - like Windows On-Screen Keyboard does.
I Need Simulate Windows On Screen Keyboard(OSK)

Comment: All open or active aplication, the one that has focus?

Comment: Well when you say all applications I'm not sure this is possible, do you mean sending keystrokes instead of a string?

Comment: For Example my curser in firefox i need type to firefox or my curser in notepad type string to notepad

Comment: I would recommend revising your question, could you potentially mean "any open application". That is what the Windows On-Screen Keyboard does. Also the other important bit you will need to know is the window that has Focus.

Comment: Yes Application That Focus on it.

Comment: @user3411432 I have corrected your question in light of your comments. Please review it, and if you disagree with the edit just rollback the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process[] all = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(process p in all)
{
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("k");
}
```

For send key to all process.

Hope it helps

Comment: This Code is Work But I Need Work Like Windows On Screen keyboard.type in one application other Address Bar in windows Explorer

Comment: Editting do not need my permission to remove my name? Haha //just kidding

Comment: @user3411432 So there is no need of using process you just set your keyboard topmost=true; and sendkey,that's all

Comment: @user3411432 This answers the question you wrote! So, please edit the question and make sure it asks what you wanted to ask, and not something else.

Comment: how to use this item?

Comment: @ANeves I got one more interesting answer that is more working than this one can I post another answer?

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years sure. Check this question in meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28471/two-answers-one-question

Answer (score 0):

assuming `s` is the string you want to send to the app that has  focus:

```
 Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, false, 5, 100);
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^V");
```

The above code as you can figure simulates a copy-paste action of string s to the application that has focus...

Comment: No this Copy text to clipboard i need type Text to for example address bar in firefox if firefox is focus on it